# Are these vectors dependent or not?

Tags: vectors

I have three vectors  $v_1 =(2,-1,3)$ ,$v_2=(1,-2,1)$ , $v_3=(3,0,5)$. 
My teacher said that those vectors are independent but I watched a tutorial in Khan Academy about dependence of vectors and from that tutorial I understood that if we multiply some of those vectors with some scalars and get the non-zero multiply of one of them, then they are dependent because,  $-2*v_1+v_2=-1*v_3$ , $-2*(2,-1,3)+(1,-2,1)=-1*(3,0,5)$ 
 => $(-4,2,-6)+(1,-2,1)=(-3,0,-5)$ => $(-4+1,2-2,-6+1)=(-3,0,-5)$ => 
$(-3,0,5)=(-3,0,-5)$  or if we put all vectors in one side and multiply with the current scalars $-2,1,1$ then they equal to $0$  , I am doing it right or not?

Comment: You are right but in your proof the implication signs should run the other way, from something true to what you want to prove. Just write $−2∗(2,−1,3)+(1,−2,1)=(-3,0,-5)=−1∗(3,0,5)$.

Comment: You are right . They are not independent.

Comment: If they were independent,then the all the scalars would be equal to zero and since they are  not and hence all three vectors are coplanar

Answer (score 1):

we have to solve $$\alpha[2;-1;3]+\beta[1;-2;1]+\gamma[3;0;5]=[0;0;0]$$
from the second equation we have
$$\alpha=-2\beta$$
plugging this in the other two equations we get
$$-3\beta+3\gamma=0$$
$$-5\beta+5\gamma=0$$
this means that your vectors are linear dependent

Comment: the three vectors are coplanar...right?

Comment: they are linear dependent and three linear dependent vectors are coplanar

Comment: Is there a reason for that

Comment: one vector can written as a linear combination of the two others

Comment: yes that's how I did thank you for the answer I just wasn't quite sure

Answer (score 1):

To show that these vectors are linearly independent we can show that the matrix equation $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution $x=0$ where $A$ is the matrix with $v_1,v_2,v_3$ as its columns. Since this matrix $A$ will be square in this case, it suffices to show $\det(A)\neq 0$ to show linear independence of $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

$$\begin{align}\det(A)&=\det\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\-1&-2&0\\3&1&5\end{bmatrix}\\&=3((-1)(1)-(3)(-2))+5((2)(-2)-(-1)(1))\\&=3(5)+5(-3)\\&=0\end{align}$$

> Since $\det(A)=0$ these vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are indeed linearly **dependent** as you say.

---

The way you do it (i.e. by finding a non trivial solution to $av_1+bv_2+cv_3=0$) is identical to the above method. Essentially, we are trying to find a way to write $v_i$ as a linear combination of the other two vectors for some $i$, and this will establish linear dependence. If no such solution exists, then the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: yes I did like that but our teacher just used dot multiplication of the vectors and then added the result and it was different from 0 and she said they are independent but I see her method is wrong thanks